# Symfony 2: How to edit persisted objects in embedded forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have the following entities:

// Entities

```
class propertiesGeneral{

    /**
     * @var abc\NikBundle\Entity\propertiesFinancial $finances
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="propertiesFinancial", mappedBy="property", cascade= {"persist", "remove", "merge"}))
     */
    protected $finances;

   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    protected $generalfield1;

    protected $generalfield2;
}

class propertiesFinancial{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="propertiesGeneral", inversedBy="finances")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="property_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
     protected $property;

     protected $financialfield1;

     protected $financialfield2;
}
```

So I have the following form to persist a new propertiesGeneral and propertiesFinancial object:

```
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder();
$form = $builder
            ->add('general',new GeneralType, array(
                  'label' => false
            ))
            ->add('finances',new FinancesType,array(
                  'label' => false
            ))
            ->add('price_rent','text',array(
                  'mapped' => false,
            ))
            ->add('price_buy','text',array(
                  'mapped' => false,
            ))
            ->getForm();
```

while the GeneralType form is:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('generalfield1',null)
    ->add('generalfield2',null)
}
```

while the Financial form is:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('financialfield1',null)
    ->add('financialfield2',null)
}
```

This code works fine to persist a propertiesGeneral and a propertiesFinancial object in database. But my problem is how to edit an existing record. So I want to have the same form with the default values of the fields to be the corresponding values from the objects retrieved from the database. Is it somehow possible using the same form?

Answer (score -1):

In your form class (Type) you can define `setDefaultOptions` method:

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'FQCN of your entity like Acme/Entity/propertiesGeneral',
    ));
}
```

How it works:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new GeneralType(), new propertiesGeneral());
```

or

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new GeneralType(), $propertiesGeneralObject);
```

Also, please read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html for more information.

Comment: "$this->createForm(new FinancialType(), new propertiesFinancial());"
is useful for creating a simple form but not suitable for embedded forms...

Comment: @iiirxs Define same hierarchy for Types as you have in Entity. We  are using forms with data_class, which is harder than yours :) http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: I moved "->add('finances',new FinancesType,array(
                  'label' => false
            ))" in GeneralType still the form is empty when displayed. I wonder if the only solution for embedded forms is to load the default values manually or use EventListener.

Comment: `->add('finances', 'collection', array('type' => new FinancesType()))` try this.